# Hyper-V/WMI programming Question

Tags: wmi, hyper-v, wmi-query

I've looked at several objects in the "root\virtualization" name space but I have not been able to find where Hyper-V stores the path to the config file for a given virtual machine. I need to get this file path programmatically or at least just the home path of a given virtual machine would be fine as well. What WMI object and field stores the path to a given virtual machine (hint it's not Msvm_ComputerSystem) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the DefaultExternalDataRoot property of Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementServiceSettingData to get the vm root, and append the Name property of Msvm_ComputerSystem (guid) and ".xml". Even if the VM is created in a non-default location, you'll see a symlink in the default external data root directory referencing the config file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not completely true. In `WSS2008R2`, when changing default VM data root, nothing is written in the system data root. To find the data root of a single VM, you need to look in `Msvm_VirtualSystemGlobalSettingData`, search for `SystemName` property matching your `VM GUID` and look in `ExternalDataRoot` and `SnapshotDataRoot` properties to see the VM related folders.